# Jquery insertAfter only once if element exist

Tags: jquery

How to check if an element exist , and if it does i want the insertAfter to be not valid.And if the element isn't exist, then i want the insertAfter to be valib but only once.My goal is to send only once insertAfter if an element isn't existing and if it does not send anything

Comment: Insert what element after which element in response to what event? What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do a length check. Assuming you have a selector `#sel`, and you want to insert something after it.

```
var foo = 'something';
if ($('#sel').length) {
   //do something if elem is present
} else {
    $('#sel').insertAfter(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if an element exists by checking the `length` property of any jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

Place the following, after amending it to your needs, inside the event handler of your choice:

```
if (!$('elementID').length) {
    $('<div id="elementID" />').insertAfter('elementSelector');
}
```

For example:

```
$('elementSelector').once().click(
    function(){
        if (!$('elementID').length) {
            $('<div id="elementID" />').insertAfter('elementSelector');
        }
    });
```

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/once/)

Comment: I think you should use one() instead of once().